# SAPUI5 Smart Table - Smart Field make field mandatory with annotation

Tags: annotations, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to make a Property in SAPUI5 Smart Table mandatory so that a user can't leave a field empty while editing it?

I have found [this document](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/SAP+Annotations+for+OData+Version+2.0) saying that it should be possible to set mandatory field control on Property in metadata.xml file with annotation like this:

```
<Property Name="NameLast" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Last name" sap:field-control="7" />
```

But with this setting I am getting following error in console:

```
2017-04-14 11:37:36.691429 MockServer: Resource not found for the segment '7' 
2017-04-14 11:37:36.707985 The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed404,Not Found,{"error":{"code":404,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment '7'"}}} -
```

EDIT:

Later I found out that sap:field-control should not contain number, but a path expression to another property which contains the number. However this also doesn't work:

```
<Property Name="NameLast" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" sap:label="Last name" sap:field-control="Name_fc" />
<Property Name="Name_fc" Type="Edm.Byte" />
```

Value of Name_fc property is '7'. I don't see any console error now, however I can still leave the input (NameLast) field empty without any validation and send it to OData service, which is not what I expect.

Here is a link to an example from sap where they use required fields. I have no idea though how they made it.
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield/code/SmartField.view.xml

Comment: Could you please also post the full metadata.xml ?

Comment: metadata.xml is here - https://jsfiddle.net/sL2zrt8j/

Answer (score 0):

> For OData v2 the sap:field-control annotation on the Property can be
>   used to specify whether the field is mandatory.

```
 <Property Name="Customer" ... sap:field-control="mandatory"/>   
 <Property Name="CompanyCode" ... sap:field-control="mandatory"/>
```

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField.html

Comment: Unfortunately your solution leads to the same error:

Resource not found for the segment 'mandatory' -  

The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed404,Not Found,{"error":{"code":404,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment 'mandatory'"}}}

Answer (score 0):

The mandatory property of the entity has to be `nullable="false"`. That's it.

Have a look at the smart field example from your link:

```
            <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"
                MaxLength="30" sap:label="Name" sap:creatable="false"
                sap:quickinfo="Property annotation DataFieldWithUrl"
                sap:updatable="true" sap:sortable="false" />
```

Btw. thanks for sharing your smart table example!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there are 2 options:

1) Define a specific property as Mandatory --> **Nullable="false"**

2) Link a property to another property in the entity, the "field-control".
This field control can contain numbers and "7" means mandatory.

The linking from option 2 can be done in the MPC_EXT class (redefine the define method).
The actual value in the "field-control" property is set in the get_entity / get_en

However I am also having an issue with the smarttable. The mandatory fields do not light up red when empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in brute force way in the Object Page extension controller.

```
var oField = this.getView().byId(<FieldId>)
oField.getDataProperty().property.nullable = "false" or "true". 
"false" and "true" must be a string.
```

To convert a boolean to string use `<boolean>.toString();`